# Python - Notion API - Can't import module

Tags: python, python-import, notion-api

I'm trying to use Notion API for some automation processes but I am having some trouble importing the packages and I already try a lot of imports. I've this code:

```
from notion_database.database import Database
my_token = "my_token"
D = Database(integrations_token=my_token )
print(D.list_databases(page_size=100))
```

To run this code I made the following imports:

```
pip install notion-database
pip install notion-py
pip install "notion==0.0.25"
pip install notion
```

All of them were installed correctly and I don't have my script name as "notion.py" :D

But when I run my code I got:

```
from notion_database.database import Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notion_database'
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks your code is fine.
More likely, your python and pip points onto two different python versions.

I would suggest you create an environment (virtualenv or pyenv) and reinstall the packages using this command:

```
sudo python -m pip install notion-database
sudo python -m pip install notion-py
sudo python -m pip install "notion==0.0.25"
sudo python -m pip install notion
```

Comment: Thanks Jerome :) I was able to run once I change to Python 32 bit version ( I was running a 64 bit)

Comment: @tech_data I am not sure that moving to 32 bits python makes it work. I have just tested your code on a 64 bits python 3.8.5 and it works like a charm. In other words, I believe that changing to 32 bits had the effect to get python and pip aligned in versions. Though I am happy it works for you !

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have not install `notion` successfully.
try to replace `pip install notion`
to `pip install notion --user`
,after that maybe there is no error with run "import notion".
good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It is also very likely, that you named your file `notion.py` in your project folder. Just rename it to something else!

It helped for some people like [here](https://github.com/jamalex/notion-py/issues/253).

Comment: I didn't named my file as notion.py :) I mentioned that on the post